# Adicionar um mês em jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho a seguinte data:

> 2017-12-22 (22 de Dezembro de 2017);

Precisaria de um incremento que somasse + 1 mês ao atual, retornando:

> 2018-01-22 (22 De Janeiro de 2018).

Como faço isso em jQuery?

Comment: Precisa ser em jquery? Com javascript puro vc faz isso facil.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date); // "2017-10-04T20:36:17.560Z"
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
console.log(date); // "2017-11-04T21:36:17.560Z"
```

Usa o `.getMonth()` para saber o mês da data, e depois usa o `.setMonth()` para mudar o mês.

Depois para mostrar formatado pode ser por exemplo assim:

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date); // "2017-10-04T20:36:17.560Z"
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
console.log(date); // "2017-11-04T21:36:17.560Z"

var formatadoA = date.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR');
console.log(formatadoA); // dá 04/11/2017

var formatadoB = [
  date.getDate(), date.getMonth() + 1, date.getFullYear()
].map(nr => nr < 10 ? '0' + nr : nr).join('-');
console.log(formatadoB); // dá 04-11-2017
```

Comment: Ele me retornou Sat Nov 04 2017 17:53:06 GMT-0200 (Horário brasileiro de verão) - https://s1.postimg.org/1y7pntf07j/1111.png
Tudo da forma como eu queria, mas como faço para formatar esse dado da seguinte maneira: "04-11-2017";

Comment: @WebCraft podes usar maneiras diferentes. Juntei duas variantes à resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Sou iniciante, mas consegui entender perfeitamente seu código. :)

Answer (score 0):

Se for só para acrescentar o mês pode se fazer assim como segue no link

```
function calcularMes(){
    var dataIncial = $('#checkin').val();
    var dataArray = dataIncial.split('/');
    var dia = dataArray[0];
    var mes = parseInt(dataArray[1]) + 1;
    var ano = dataArray[2];

    var novaData = dia + "/"+ mes + "/"+ano;
    $('#checkout').val( novaData );

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cbcarlos/0rj21xsq/

Comment: O código que tem no fiddle ficaria melhor como um snippet executável diretamente na resposta. Torna-se mais pratico a qualquer pessoa que esteja a ver a resposta de ler e código e executa-lo. Assim como está acaba por não ter nada na resposta a não ser o proprio link.

Comment: Eu tentei fazer pelo snippet diretamente na resposta, mas algumas bibliotecas não funcionaram, por isso adicionei pelo jsfiddle